# SQL php connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003):
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on '209.**.**.**' (13) in
>   /home/www/hookahondemond.com/Sendorder01010101010101.php on line 77
>   Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '209.**.***.***' (13)

my php code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("209.17.116.155","mir****","M****6","stores",'3306');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: does the machine accept connections from the outside to the database?

Comment: Please obscure your credentials better when posting here - this is quite easy to crack. Anyway, are you sure you need to specify the external IP of the database instead of 'localhost'?

Comment: You should obfuscate the domain name, page name and IP address from your posting, or some scriptkiddies might pay you a visit.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Apache/PHP server and make sure that you can connect to the MySQL port:

```
telnet <mysql host> <mysql port>
```

If you cannot telnet the port, then it could be either one of these:

- a network (firewall? routing?) problem
- your MySQL server is currently not running
- your MySQL host/port is incorrect
- your MySQL is running but does not accept tcp connections (it has --skip-networking option set)

If you can telnet the MySQL host/port, then there is no network/MySQL setting problem,
and actually, you should be seeing a different error message (like credential error)